# Firebase POD triggering a "/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to add cocoapods and firebase to an existing ios app. (using xcode 10.1 and swift 4)
Cocoapods seem to be set up correctly, (I can use some random pods).

However when I try to add [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) (or [Crashlytics](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/mobile-attention-tracking/crashlytics)) the build fails.

the error is:
`/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

In the logs I can see this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Anyone has experienced something similar?
I have been googling around for a while now, but not too much luck, beside finding out that [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary) (from which I think the error is coming from) is deprecated

Comment: Looks like a problem with opencv2 - maybe https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/include/opencv2?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien thank you. What I found out is that I needed to add `AssetsLibrary` to `Link Binaries with Libraries`, now the project builds, but the app crashes